# Android: Granting SET_TIME permission as a Device Owner using Device Policy Manager

Tags: android, android-permissions, device-policy-manager, device-owner

I am developing a COSU/KIOSK application and I need to manually update the time on the device.

I am using `AlertManager.setTime(Calendar)` to do so, but I can't grant my application the `SET_TIME` permission that it is required.

The application is the device owner, and this allowed me to use many other system permissions, for example

```
android:name="android.permission.REBOOT"
android:name="android.permission.SHUTDOWN"
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES"
```

All of these permissions were granted to my application, just by listing them in the `manifest.xml`

But `SET_TIME` does not work.

I also tried using the device policy manager

```
mDevicePolicyManager.setPermissionGrantState(mAdminComponentName, getPreferredPackageName(),
                Manifest.permission.SET_TIME, DevicePolicyManager.PERMISSION_GRANT_STATE_GRANTED);
```

This function returned `false` meaning it couldn't grant permission.

How can I solve this problem without prompting the user to grant this permission to my application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting devices api 28+ (android 9 and higher) you can set it with [setTime(ComponentName admin, long millis)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setTime(android.content.ComponentName,%20long)) function.

For lower android versions I had to rely on a device manufacturer api to set device time.

`Manifest.permission.SET_TIME` is proteced/system permission, sadly deviceOwner cannot grant any protected permissions with `setPermissionGrantState()` function.
There is very important word in its documentation:

> Sets the grant state of a **!runtime!** permission for a specific application.

Comment: Sadly I am targeting a lower target API. My confusion comes from, that I could do other stuff that also requires system permission, for example, I was able to re-install silently an application while running, without any user interaction. Setting a new time is way less dangerous than the stuff I was able to do.

Comment: well, installing an app doesnt require system permission if you are DeviceOwner