# Start activity from background on Android 13+ with lock task mode

Tags: android, android-service, android-permissions, device-policy-manager, system-alert-window

I'm trying to start the activity of an app from a foreground service (the activity then starts the lock task mode and essentially "locks" the device). As I'm targeting devices with Android 13+, starting the activity from background requires to follow the [instructions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) introduced after Android 10. Out of them the easiest seemed to me was able to receive the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission.

I tried to grant it using the `setPermissionGrantState()` to the `Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission with `PERMISSION_GRANT_STATE_GRANTED` as grant state from a device owner but it was still revokable in the settings. I later learnt it [can't grant system protected permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64874932/5019937).

I had also tried directly modifying the OS [default permission policy](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/permission/DefaultPermissionGrantPolicy.java;l=495?q=DefaultPermission&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject) by using the `grantSystemFixedPermissionsToSystemPackage()` that also couldn't grant this as a `SYSTEM_FIXED` permission, it would grant it but not fixed.